# Getting NaN as answer for a simple Java program

Tags: java, math

I'm learning Java lately so i started converting my programs in C++ to Java but i'm getting NaN as answer when i'm calculating the distance. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here? Thank you.
Here are the codes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Labsheet1Number1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double length=0,height=0,pi=3.142;
    double distance=0,angle=0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program will calculate the distance and the angle.");
    System.out.print("Enter the length of the ladder: ");
    length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the height of the wall: ");
    height = input.nextInt();

    distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(length, 2) - Math.pow(height, 2));

    angle = (180/pi) * (Math.sin(height/length));

    System.out.println("The distance is " + distance);
    System.out.println("The angle is " + angle);
}

}
```

Comment: What input do you use?

Comment: I tried with integers.

Comment: Unrelated, but `Math.PI`.

Comment: Lol Ah thanks for the tip i'm still learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are calculating the distance between two points, the distance should be :

`distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(length, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));`

As it is, you might be computing `Math.sqrt(x)` for a negative number, which would explain the NaN (Not a Number) result.

From the JavaDoc of [Math.sqrt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) :

> If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN

EDIT :

Due to @AnthonyGrist comment, I read the question again.
While the equation for distance calculation is `dist(p1,p2) = sqrt ( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )`, based on the inputs requested from the user - `Enter the length of the ladder:` and `Enter the height of the wall:` - it seems reasonable to believe that the distance we are meant to compute is the horizontal distance of the bottom of a ladder from the bottom of the wall.

If that is the case, p1 and p2 are the locations of the ladder's edges (lets assume for simplicity the ladder is 1-dimentional), and dist(p1,p2) in the above equation is already known - it's `length`. Assuming that the ladder reaches the top of the wall, we also know that `height = abs(y1-y2)`.

Therefore, what we want to calculate is actually `abs(x1-x2)`.

If we rearrange the above equation, we get :

`distance = abs(x1-x2) = sqrt (dist(p1,p2)^2 - (y1-y2)^2) = sqrt (length^2 - height^2)`

Which is exactly the original equation in the question.

However, this equation is correct only if `height <= length` (since they ladder cannot reach the top of a wall higher than its own length). Therefore, in order to avoid invalid result (NaN), you should validate the input, and make sure `height <= length`.

Comment: Beat me to typing it.  This is the problem with the code.  When the length < height, it fails.   Change this to + and OP is good to go.

Comment: Yes, thank you, now it's working fine but in the labsheet the formula is given as such. Might be a mistake then.

Comment: @DamzZz It doesn't seem like a mistake. I assume the scenario is that you have a ladder of length `l` resting against a wall of height `h`, and you want to calculate the distance from the base of the wall where the ladder is resting on the ground, and the angle between the top of the ladder and the wall? The formula is correct, it's just a rearrangement of Pythagoras' theorum, it just doesn't work when `h` is greater than `l`.

Comment: If what I've assumed above is correct, changing the `-` to a `+` doesn't solve the issue; it gives you entirely the wrong result. In reality the height of the wall is irrelevant, what you'd actually want is the height at which the ladder rests against it, which is always going to be less than the length of the ladder.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I assumed the distance function represents a distance between two points (i.e. length = x1 - x2 and height = y1 - y2). Perhaps I assumed wrong, it's hard to tell from the question. Anyway, I answered why the OP got NaN.

Answer (score 3):

> [`Nan`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) stands for NOT a NUMBER. If a fractional operation has some inputs
>   that causes the operation to make some weird or undefined result.For
>   example square root of a negative number is undefined which is basically performed in your code for `Math.sqrt()` for **length<sup>2</sup>-height<sup>2</sup> < 0**.It can be caused by `0.0/0.0` as well but that's not the case here.